# Is there a way to pause/block Redis clients while Redis clustering

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Redis during clustering requires all nodes to be empty, but if there're connected (apps)clients who write data continuously, it's not enough time to cluster, so I need to **flushall**->pause somehow->**cluster**->unpause.

Redis **client kill** is killing but clients quickly reconnect.

Redis **client pause** is pausing all clients, but for performing clustering operations I need at least one active redis-cli client. Is there a good way to deal with it? Or it requires stopping all clients and then reconnect after clustering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution, originally I was performing script with operations

```
redis-cli -a $PASSWORD -c -h $HOST -p $PORT flushall
redis-cli -a $PASSWORD -c -h $HOST -p $PORT cluster reset soft
redis-cli -a $PASSWORD -c -h $HOST -p $PORT client pause 10000
....
redis-cli -a $PASSWORD --cluster-yes --cluster create ...

redis-cli -a $PASSWORD -c -h $HOST -p $PORT client unpause
....
```

But problem was in latency on connections, so I've wrapped the first 3 commands and performed in batch

```
 cat reset.txt | redis-cli -a $PASSWORD -c -h $HOST -p $PORT --pipe
 ....
 redis-cli -a $PASSWORD --cluster-yes --cluster create ...
 
 redis-cli -a $PASSWORD -c -h $HOST -p $PORT client unpause
 ....
```

Where reset.txt

```
 flushall
 cluster reset soft
 client pause 10000
```

So batch flushes and resets quickly before clients write data.